# What happens if Nexo defaults?

Tags: cryptocurrency, default

My question is if I deposited some crypto or fiat currency to Nexo, and Nexo defaults. How can I get my money back? I looked at their site and googled for the info but couldn't find the answer. I understand that they may be insured but this doesn't answer my question I think.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with defaulting is that you can’t get your money back. If you could (through their insurance etc), they wouldn’t be defaulting.

Answer (score 0):

Their website looks like they are designed to fleece their “investors”. I think it’s unlikely that they are going to run out of money, more likely that someone will take all the investors money into a country without extradition treaties.

I’ll have another look next year.